# Clear HTML5 placeholder attribute text on focus in Chrome

Tags: css, html, google-chrome

Is there any way I can clear `placeholder` text on focus in **Chrome**, Firefox clears the text on focus but Chrome doesn't.

This confuses the user whether the text in the bar is typed, or it's a placeholder text (Even if I changed the text color to light grey), I don't want to use unnecessary JavaScript or jQuery for this, I want to know if there's some HTML/CSS solution for this

[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5U9us/)

**Chrome Preview** (On Focus)

[image: Chrome Preview On Focus]

**Firefox Preview** (On Focus)

[image: Firefox Preview On Focus]

Comment: Don't touch the user expected behavoir!

Comment: @Bondye It is actually annoying if the text doesn't get cleared on focus..

Comment: I think is more annoying if the text DOES get cleared on focus. Because he don't attach a label or name to the input. So when I focus I don't know what I focus...

Comment: @Bondye I do show them on which field they are so no question of not knowing what a user is focusing at ;)

Comment: Why do you use a placeholder then?

Comment: I write messages in my placeholders :)

Comment: Still don't touch the behavoir like @Andy say

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Try using

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder 
{
    color: transparent;
}
```

It will resolve the issue. The text is visible on focus because of the auto focus on page load.

Comment: There you go, CSS always has a solution for everything ;)

Comment: *cough* using hacky browser specific tags *cough* :)

Comment: it was great :) I must use it with !important tag after that it works good

Answer (score 27):

Now firefox works in other way, so I used this code:

```
input:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder{
    color: transparent!important;
}
input:focus::-moz-placeholder{
    color: transparent!important;
}
input:focus:-moz-placeholder{
    color: transparent!important;
}
```

Comment: a 2 year later, of this question, i font that this is the one that works best

Answer (score 3):

This is how chrome handles it, and chrome users will probably expect it to be handled like this. You could, however, use jQuery to remove the "placeholder" attribute when it is focused on.

I found an apparent fix for you, from a google group @ https://github.com/mathiasbynens/jquery-placeholder/issues/51#issuecomment-4193018

```
// Fixing Webkit that not clearing input/textarea when get focus
$(function(){
  if ($.browser.webkit) {
    $('input, textarea').on('focus',function(){
      if ( $(this).attr('placeholder') ) $(this).data('placeholder', $(this).attr('placeholder')).removeAttr('placeholder');
}).on('blur', function(){
        if ( $(this).data('placeholder') ) $(this).attr('placeholder', $(this).data('placeholder')).removeData('placeholder');
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This answer deserves attention, it's browser-compatible while others are '-webkit-' specific.

Comment: $.browser has been deprecated for a looong time already. In order to still use it you need to load jQuery's migrate script after the core jQuery library. I'd recommend the CSS fix instead.

Answer (score -1):

I found that the Shubhanshu's solution didn't work for me, but I did find this on  [CSS tricks](https://css-tricks.com/hang-on-placeholders/) that did work in Chrome, doesn' seem to work in FF though.

```
[placeholder]:focus::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: transparent;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```css
input:hover::placeholder 
{
  color: transparent;
}
```

```html
    <input type="text" id="fname" name="firstname" placeholder="Your name..">
```